# Volterra fractional differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, differential-operators, fractional-calculus, fractional-part

İ am just stuck on this step :
If we have the following volterra fractional integral equation :
$$
x(t)=x_0+\frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^t ({t}-\tau)^{\alpha-1} f(\tau,x(\tau)) \, d\tau, \qquad t\in\left[0,{T}\right]
$$

And then let :
$$
\tau=t-(t^\alpha-\upsilon\Gamma(\alpha+1))^{1/\alpha}
$$

So Volterra  fractional integral equation can be written as :
$$
x(t)
=x_0 + \int_0^{t^\alpha/\Gamma(\alpha+1)} f(t-(t^\alpha-\upsilon\Gamma(\alpha+1))^{1/\alpha},x(t-(t^\alpha-\upsilon\Gamma(\alpha+1))^{1/\alpha})) \, d\upsilon
$$
Is there any explanation how did we write it in a the last form 
Thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple substitution or re-parametrization of the integration variable.

Set
$$
\tau=g(υ)=t-(t^\alpha-\upsilon\Gamma(\alpha+1))^{1/\alpha}
$$
then you get $τ=0$ for $υ=0$ and $τ=t$ for $t^α−υΓ(α+1)=0$ or $ υ=\frac{t^α}{Γ(α+1)}$. Furthermore, $dτ=g'(υ)\,dυ$ with
$$
g'(υ)=\frac1αΓ(α+1)(t^α−υΓ(α+1))^{\frac1α-1}.
$$
Note that $Γ(α+1)=αΓ(α)$ by definition of the Gamma function.